# .gitignore still including files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

I downloaded `.gitignore` for C# (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/CSharp.gitignore) for my repo (https://github.com/feick/Water-Tank). I included the `.gitignore` in the first commit, then I made a second commit with the project files. On my repo, it is still showing unwanted folders/files that should have been excluded while using `.gitignore` (/bin,/obj,etc.). I'm assuming it's a user error on my part, so I was wondering if someone could let me know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename `CSharp.gitignore` file to `.gitignore`

Comment: I renamed it to `.gitignore`, then deleted the [original project files](https://github.com/feick/Water-Tank) and recommitted so the file would work. Unfortunately, this still hasn't worked.

Comment: @feick In your repo, it says `gitignore`, not `.gitignore`, the dot is important.

Comment: don't rename from explorer (it does not allow a leading dot in file name), use console: `ren gitignore .gitignore`

Comment: Renamed `gitignore` in terminal using `mv gitignore .gitignore`, then deleted project and recommitted. Folders and files are now ignored, thank you.

Comment: @max I almost spent all my life looking after a solution. Only your suggestion helped me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already committed those files to your repo, you have to remove them (using `git rm`, for example) and commit.

The bad part is that the binaries will still live forever on the repo, so you should probably delete and recreate it.

Comment: What is the downside of the binaries staying on the repo, disk space?

Comment: Essentially, yes. And everyone cloning the repo will get them.